# RBAC togehter with AAA?

Tags: network, rbac

I'm taking a network course and my teacher has not been answering my emails.
I'm supposed to set up "Role based access using privileges with AAA" I thought RBAC and AAA stood in contrast to one and other?

I know that `aaa new model` must be configured in order to create views, but other than that aren't AAA and RBAC different techniques?

Answer (score 1):

Authentication, authorization, and accounting (AAA) is a term for a framework for controlling access to computer resources, enforcing policies and auditing usage. RBAC (Role Based Access Control) is a way that dictates how a subject can access objects. Two other forms beside RBAC are the highly restrictive mandatory access control model (MAC) is compared to the discretionary access control model (DAC) which allows the creator/owner of an object to grant access as he or she sees fit.

So in your case AAA will provide the steps to identification and authentication the subject, the first A. The second A will be selecting the privileges the subject has to the object it is trying to access and this can be determined based on the MAC, DAC or RBAC-model. Third the last A that you can account for the actions done by the subject in the previous steps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about configuring Cisco equipment here (based on the `aaa new model` remark). You can use AAA there to map (groups of) users to specific privilege levels. You can assign a set of allowed commands to each privilege level. This makes AAA on Cisco a form of RBAC.